# aligning 3 images in HTML and CSS without table

Tags: html, css, styling

Im trying to align 2 images and some text.
I do not want to use a table to do this.

Is there a way to do it using inline styling?
I would like them to all be equally spaced as well.

IMG 1 > TEXT > IMG 2

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with flexbox:

HTML

```
<div>
    <img />
    <p>text</p>
    <img />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

More info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: this method works but now my h1 tag (the text) is not vertically aligned. Its towards the top of the div, is there a way i can centre it vertically?

Comment: Try `align-items: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch;` - one of those should work. It should be in the div selector.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at the guide I put in my answer, flexbox is a great tool. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Updated**

```css
div {
    text-align: justify;
    display:table;
}

span{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:0 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="http://www.raisedeyebrow.com/sites/www.raisedeyebrow.com/files/blog/2012/01/fff.png" alt=""  /> 
 <span>Text Here</span>
 <img src="http://www.raisedeyebrow.com/sites/www.raisedeyebrow.com/files/blog/2012/01/fff.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want every div to change though, how do i choose that one div in question?

Comment: i've updated the answer, check if that's what you're looking for!